# Is there any way to multiply each number in String using regex?

Tags: java, regex

I need to increase each number String in two times. For example "32abcd54ab2abcd5" should be "64abcd108ab4abcd10". Is there any way to do this using regex, but not writing special function?

```java
import java.util.regex.*;

class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String s= "2aaa3bbb4";
        Pattern p1 = Pattern.compile("(\\d+)");
        Matcher m1 = p1.matcher(s);
        String newString = m1.replaceAll(Integer.parseInt("$1") * 2 + "");
    }
}
```

Comment: Briefly, no. You'll have to identify the numbers (perhaps split using a regexp, similar to the above...), multiply and then reassemble...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use a lambda in the `Matcher#replaceAll` as the replacement argument since Java 9:

```
String s= "2aaa3bbb4 67";
Pattern p1 = Pattern.compile("\\d+");
Matcher m = p1.matcher(s);
String result = m.replaceAll(x -> String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(x.group()) * 2) );
System.out.println( result );
// => 4aaa6bbb8 134
```

A vartiation for older Java versions should be based on `Matcher#appendReplacement`:

```
String s= "2aaa3bbb4 67";
Pattern p1 = Pattern.compile("\\d+");
Matcher m = p1.matcher(s);
            
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
while (m.find()) {
    m.appendReplacement(sb, Integer.parseInt(m.group()) * 2 + "");
}
m.appendTail(sb);
System.out.println( sb.toString() );
```

See a [Java demo](https://rextester.com/IEZSK21614).

Answer (score 2):

Not sure but Something like this might help.

```
  String oldString = "32abcd54ab2abcd5";
  char[] chars = oldString.toCharArray();
  for(char c : chars){
     if(Character.isDigit(c)){
        c = Integer.parseInt(c); 
        c = c *2 ;
        c = Integer.toString(int c);
     }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

First split the string into numbers and letters `[2, aaa, 3, bbb, 4]` and traverse the stream if the element is a number `e.matches("\\d+")` then multiply with 2 then collect to a new String value.

Try this:

```
String s= "2aaa3bbb4";
String[] str = s.split("(?<=\\D)(?=\\d)|(?<=\\d)(?=\\D)");

String result = Arrays.stream(str).map(e -> e.matches("\\d+") ? String.valueOf(Integer.valueOf(e)*2) : e)
    .collect(Collectors.joining());

System.out.println(result);
```

Output:

```
4aaa6bbb8
```